# Swift: ios-chart tap handler not working properly

Tags: ios, swift, ios-charts

I have the following chart:

[image: graphView]

When I tap on Sunday, Monday and Wednesday bars, it does not respond. When I tap on Tue bar, it responds and correctly print "2" (meaning it third bar). When I tap on rest of bars in the table, it prints "4" which basically mean Thursday bar was tapped.

This is my code:

```
@IBOutlet weak var graphView: BarChartView!
func updateGraph(){
    var dataEntries: [BarChartDataEntry] = []
    let timeSheet: TimeSheet = TimeSheet.getTimeSheet()
    let weekData = timeSheet.getData()
    let keys: [String] = weekData.allKeys as! [String]
    for weekday in keys{
        let _weekday = weekday == "Sunday" ? 0 : weekday == "Monday" ? 1 : weekday == "Tuesday" ? 2: weekday == "Wednesday" ? 3 : weekday == "Thursday" ? 4 : weekday == "Friday" ? 5 : 6
        let dayData = weekData.value(forKeyPath: weekday) as! NSDictionary
        var totalWorkHour: Double = Double(dayData["totalWorkHour"] as! NSNumber)
        totalWorkHour = Double(Int(totalWorkHour)/60*100 + Int(totalWorkHour)%60)/100  //Chaing minutes to hour format
        let entry = BarChartDataEntry(x: Double(_weekday), y: totalWorkHour)
        dataEntries.append(entry)
    }
    let graphDataSet = BarChartDataSet(values: dataEntries, label: nil)
    graphDataSet.colors = ChartColorTemplates.colorful()  //Make bars colorful
    graphDataSet.axisDependency = .left
    //graphDataSet.barBorderWidth = graphDataSet.barBorderWidth/2
    let graphData = BarChartData(dataSet: graphDataSet)
    graphView.data = graphData
}

func chartValueSelected(_ chartView: ChartViewBase, entry: ChartDataEntry, highlight: Highlight){
    print("\(entry.x)")
}
```

I basically followed [ios-charts-api-tutorial](https://www.appcoda.com/ios-charts-api-tutorial/).

Please let me know if you figure out something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, it was issue of appending order. It seems like if we insert data not in order (i.e Thu, Fri, Tue, Sat...), tap action goes wrong.
I solved this issue by sorting my dictionary in Sun, Mon, Tue, Wed...